# Are node.js and VisualStudio really the only well maintained options to build typescript?

Tags: windows, typescript, eclipse, sass

I work in eclipse on windows.

I have a workspace containing several projects, one of which contains typescript and sass (scss) files. I had a working build chain that produced a solid output of CSS and JS files. However I created this a while back, and I never really liked the way it was set up to begin with. Now external circumstances force me to rethink this chain, and I want to rebuild it more robust.

I previously used webpack via nodejs, triggered from a package.json from inside eclipse.
I don't like this, because I dislike the idea of a build chain that depends on an ecosystem, which is difficult to upgrade safely (without a clear strategy of reverting to a stable state, in case of failure or incompatibility). This is exactly what happened to me, and why I want to leave this setup.

What I would like to have is a:

- fixed version of a (preferably more atomic) transpiler that I can try to upgrade/update manually, but always know to have the old version to fall back on.
- less 'messy' chain, with as few individual pieces as possible.
- still maintained solution.

What I had in mind was a Maven based chain, but those approaches always seems to rely on other tools, which in turn use nodejs. I'd rather use a separate build chain to build SASS, and have a robust typescript build chain in trade.

Answer (score 1):

The [official TypeScript compiler](https://www.typescriptlang.org) is the only TypeScript compiler that provides type checking. It's a Node.js program.

[Babel](https://babeljs.io) and some similar tools can also transpile TypeScript into JavaScript but all they do is to strip type annotations (after all TypeScript syntax is just JavaScript + some modern ECMAScript features + type annotations). It's very useful and fast for production builds but basically defeats the purpose of using TypeScript in the first place, which is presumably type checking. Besides, all of the tools of this type that I'm aware of are also Node.js programs.

What this means is that you're already going to need Node.js for the compiler itself.

Coming from mainly C/C++ programming I also disliked the idiosyncrasy of JS build tools and tried hard to avoid them. But it is what it is: You're on your own if you want to use tools like make, maven, or similar. It is also *slower*. TypeScript (or Babel) compiler is an in process plugin for Webpack, but it's gonna be an external command if you use a generic build system. This adds overhead and causes the compilers to do some extra work in some settings. Finally, extremely useful Webpack features like the watch mode and the dev server are not easily implementable with a traditional build system.

Besides, I don't think your objections are warranted: It is, in fact, very easy to revert an npm package to a stable state if you use version control (which you should be doing anyway) and a [package-lock.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/package-lock-json.html) file. Then it's a simple matter of `git checkout stable-branch && npm ci`. Here, `ci` stands for "clean install" and it installs all the packages with the version numbers in `package-lock.json`. You can even install a checkout hook that runs `npm ci` when there are changes in the `package-lock.json` (which you should commit to your version control system).

This way, everyone in your team and every build of your application (be it your local development version, your colleagues' development versions, staging servers, or production server, or whatever) will have the exact same npm packages for a given git commit (or equivalent thereof in other version control systems).